# Create Hyperlink to Cell in Another Workbook/CSV VBA

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, reference

I'm currently working on a script in WorkbookA that notifies of a change in another Workbook (WorkbookB). I would like to add the functionality of being taken to that Workbook if the user would like to see the change. Currently, I'm running the code:

```
SelRangeA(iRow, 2) = "=HYPERLINK(""[C:\..\WorkbookB.csv]Sheet1!B4"",""CLICK HERE"")"
```

Which displays the proper Hyperlink in the spreadsheet : `Click Here` with contents:

```
=HYPERLINK("[C:\..\WorkbookB.csv]Sheet1!B4","CLICK HERE")
```

However when I follow the link, it opens the requested Workbook with an error:

> Reference is not valid.

Any insight on how to properly reference the required cell? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CSV file won't contain a "Sheet1".  The "sheet" name is derived from the name of the file.

So your code needs to be:

```
=HYPERLINK("[C:\..\WorkbookB.csv]'" & filename & "'!B4","CLICK HERE")
```

where `filename` has been set to the base part of the CSV file's filename (i.e. it needs to equate to "WorkbookB" in your example).

Comment: Nice catch, missed the csv detail

Comment: I'll just use this Answer to reply to both you and @cyboashu :P . This makes sense as when I looked at the csv file once it was opened - the first sheet name was WorkbookB (in this example). However it's still throwing the Reference is not valid. error :/ Any other thoughts?

Comment: @TylerDickson - The statement `=HYPERLINK("[L:\xyz\Temp\Temp1.csv]'Temp1'!B4")` works for me.  I assume your `..` is just hiding the actual path you are using, and is not an attempt to access the parent directory of the current directory.  Are you getting the error when the file is **actually** WorkbookB.csv, or are you doing your testing with another (real) file?  (I included the `'` marks around the sheet name to avoid problems with spaces in the name but, if your workbook name contains some other weird character, it may not be the name that Excel uses for the sheetname.)

Comment: @TylerDickson - e.g. A filename of "Temp1[1]Copy.csv" will be loaded into Excel with a sheetname of "Temp1(1)Copy", because the "[" and "]" are not valid characters in sheet names.

Comment: After ALOT of troubleshooting, I managed to get the file to open when I changed the internal Sheet name to Sheet1. I find it odd that there is no way to default to the first Sheet when referencing another document - but I guess this solution is manageable. My final code snippet ended up looking like this: `=HYPERLINK("[WorkbookB.csv]Sheet1!B4","CLICK HERE")`. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @TylerDickson - I'm glad it's working for you, but I must admit that I can't understand how you changed a CSV file to have a "sheet" name that wasn't the file name.  A .csv file (assuming it is just a comma-separated value text file and not, for instance, an Excel spreadsheet saved with a non-standard file extension) just contains text, with no way of storing any meta-data such as a sheetname.  So, although you could change the sheetname while it is open, once you close the file and open it again the sheetname will revert to the normal one.

Comment: @YowE3K - Yea I think a majority of the issues on my end were just that - on my end. We receive these csv's from another company and I'm thinking that they are just saving .xls files as .csv (which makes life more difficult on our end). Now that you mention it, the data they send us already looks formatted in Excel when the csv is opened, so I probably should've clued in earlier. But even when I changed this file to a .xls format, I was still running into errors until I changed the sheet name to Sheet1. Would you happen to know a way to select the first Sheet without specifying a name?

Comment: @TylerDickson - As far as I know, you can't do that with just a HYPERLINK function.  (If using VBA you could open each of the workbooks that you were linking to, determine which was the first [only] sheet name, then modify the hyperlinks - but I can't see how that would be the most practical solution to any real-world problem.)

Comment: @TylerDickson - just using `=HYPERLINK("C:\..\WorkbookB.csv","CLICK HERE")` would work, but only open up to the first cell in the sheet, not to a specific cell.  (But the fact that yours isn't a real CSV file may mean it might have the same issue as you currently have.)

Answer (score 1):

If the link is in another workbook and you want Excel to open it if it isn't already open, you need to specify both the address and the sub-address (kind of like an anchor in an HTML link):

```
SelRangeA(iRow, 2) = "=HYPERLINK(""C:\Foo.xlsx#[C:\Foo.xlsx]Sheet1!A1"")"
```

EDIT: Note that for a `.csv` file, the worksheet name will default to the file name on open:

```
SelRangeA(iRow, 2) = "=HYPERLINK(""C:\Foo.csv#[C:\Foo.csv]Foo!A1"")"
                                                         '^^^
```

Comment: I tried this and was confronted with the error: the name that you entered is not valid reasons for this could include: ...

Comment: @TylerDickson - You need to use the actual document, sheet, and cell names.  As YowE3K points out, the sheet name will be the file name for a CSV.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to define a name (Formulas->Name Manager) whenever certain cells get changed. For example if the name was defined as "changedcell" you would set the hyperlink as follows:

=HYPERLINK("[C:..\WorkbookB.csv#changedcell]","CLICK HERE")

Just make sure the scope of the name is set to full workbook if there are multiple worksheets.

Comment: This would work, but the Workbook2 is going to be changing to a new file alot so I don't think I'll be able to keep the Name Manager consistent